# How to drop mongodb collection using C++?

Tags: c++, mongodb

I'm asking this trivial question, because there are absolutely no tutorials and zero examples on the Web. The only thing that exists - is a C++ [driver](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_with_commands.html). In the source code of the driver I see a method called `dropCollection`, and it is defined like this:

```
virtual bool dropCollection (const string &ns, BSONObj *info=NULL)
```

But unfortunately, documentation does not shed any light on how to use this method. Intuitively, I thought that one of its arguments should be a collection name, but here I see only the strange argument &ns (I guess namespace) - what it means - I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this **[thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/11eLdrc8DUk)**, you can use `dropCollection(std::string ns)` as in the following example:

```
mongo::DBClientConnection c;
c.connect("localhost");
//perform inserts, updates
c.dropCollection("databaseName.collectionName");
```